# My nav bar won't center and keeps moving either right or left

Tags: html, css

I've been going around the web trying to find an answer to how to center my navbar but none of the solution worked.

The code below will show what I have so far with both HTML and CSS.

```css
header {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  padding-top: 30px;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: #000000 3px solid;
}

header a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
}

header li {
  float: center;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

header nav {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

header #smcontent {
  float: left;
}

header #smcontent a {
  margin: 0;
}

header #smcontent img {
  width: 20px;
}

header .logoimg .center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 20%;
}

header a:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="smcontent">
      <a href="https://twitter.com/">
        <img src="./images/twitter.png">
      </a>
      <a href="https://facebook.com/">
        <img src="./images/facebook.png">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="logoimg">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img class="center" src="./images/portfolio.png">
      </a>
    </div>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="story.html">Story</a></li>
        <li><a href="product.html">Product</a></li>
        <li><a href="clinique.html">Clinique</a></li>
        <li><a href="promo.html">Promotions</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

This is how it looks like right now:

[image: This is how it looks like right now]

I have also noticed that in CSS, when I did "float: center;" it had no difference with when I did "float: left;". But when I did "float: right;" it would shift to the right.

Comment: First of all there no such property exists. We have only float: left and float: right;
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

Comment: just u want to align nav bar contents(home,story,product,....) in center ?@Gomox Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
ul {
  margin: 0 auto; 
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  padding-top: 30px;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: #000000 3px solid;
}

header a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
}

header li {
  float: center;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

header nav {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header #smcontent a {
  margin: 0;
}

header #smcontent img {
  width: 20px;
}

header .logoimg .center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 20%;
}

header a:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="smcontent">
      <a href="https://twitter.com/">
        <img src="./images/twitter.png">
      </a>
      <a href="https://facebook.com/">
        <img src="./images/facebook.png">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="logoimg">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img class="center" src="./images/portfolio.png">
      </a>
    </div>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="story.html">Story</a></li>
        <li><a href="product.html">Product</a></li>
        <li><a href="clinique.html">Clinique</a></li>
        <li><a href="promo.html">Promotions</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
   </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

I have removed the below css from your code

`header #smcontent {
  float: left;
}`

and added `margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;` to the `ul`

Comment: This worked to a certain extent as well. The navbar is centered and it is perfect but the social media logos moved to the center as well. 
https://imgur.com/a/sJDqMma

Comment: I thought you also wanted them to be centered! Fixing please check

Comment: My pleasure @GomoxLee

Answer (score 0):

Try absolute position with float none, left 50% and a left translate of 50% to center your nav bar perfectly.

CSS: add

```
header .newCenter {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

HTML: add

```
    <nav class="newCenter">
      <ul>
        <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="story.html">Story</a></li>
        <li><a href="product.html">Product</a></li>
        <li><a href="clinique.html">Clinique</a></li>
        <li><a href="promo.html">Promotions</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: So it worked to a certained extent. Now the navbar is centered but it moved under the solid line that I put.
https://imgur.com/a/8GZNtWI

Answer (score 0):

Float only applies to left and right. I added `display: grid` and `justify-content: center` to your header. I removed `float: left;` in header #smcontent.

```css
header {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  padding-top: 30px;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: #000000 3px solid;
  display: grid; //or flex
  justify-content: center; 
}

header a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
}

header li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

header nav {
  margin: 10px auto 0;
}

header #smcontent a {
  margin: 0;
}

header #smcontent img {
  width: 20px;
}

header .logoimg .center {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 20%;
}


header a:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="smcontent">
      <a href="https://twitter.com/">
        <img src="./images/twitter.png">
      </a>
      <a href="https://facebook.com/">
        <img src="./images/facebook.png">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="logoimg">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img class="center" src="./images/portfolio.png">
      </a>
    </div>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="story.html">Story</a></li>
        <li><a href="product.html">Product</a></li>
        <li><a href="clinique.html">Clinique</a></li>
        <li><a href="promo.html">Promotions</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score -1):

To align text horizontally center use `text-align:center`. In your to align nav bar content center just add `text-align:center` to  `header nav`

```
header nav {
  margin-left: auto;

  text-align:center; 

  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

In below code snippet I have added some images for demonstration purpose.

```css
    header {
      background: #ffffff;
      color: #000000;
      padding-top: 30px;
      min-height: 70px;
      border-bottom: #000000 3px solid;
    }

    header a {
      color: #000000;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 16px;
    }

    header li {
      float: center;
      display: inline;
      padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    }

    header nav {
      margin-left: auto;
      text-align:center;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }

    header #smcontent {
      float: left;
    }

    header #smcontent a {
      margin: 0;
    }

    header #smcontent img {
      width: 20px;
    }

    header .logoimg .center {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 20%;
    }

    header a:hover {
      color: #cccccc;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="smcontent">
          <a href="https://twitter.com/">
            <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/kiev-ukraine-may-26-2015twitter-260nw-281505518.jpg">
          </a>
          <a href="https://facebook.com/">
            <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/kiev-ukraine-april-27-2015-260nw-278925056.jpg">
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="logoimg">
          <a href="index.html">
            <img class="center" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png">
          </a>
        </div>

        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="story.html">Story</a></li>
            <li><a href="product.html">Product</a></li>
            <li><a href="clinique.html">Clinique</a></li>
            <li><a href="promo.html">Promotions</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
              </div>

    </header>
```